# Regex in vim while doing replace

Tags: regex, vim

I have a text file with many statements like: "1", "23",..... etc and I want to replace these occurrences with 1, 23,.... etc. That is just removing the quotes. How can I do this in VIM?

Comment: you should maybe run `vimtutor`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use :

```
:%s/"\(\d\+\)"/\1/g
```

Which means: replace any sequence of digits between double quotes with the sequence of digits itself.

For more reference:

```
:help :s
:help pattern
```

Comment: Useful example of search command, but IMHO simple `s/"//g` do "just removing the quotes" as requested in the question

Answer (score 2):

You type esc then:

```
:%s/\"\([0-9]*\)\"/\1/g
```

This will substitute the pattern: " any digits " by any digits.
Note that `\1` will replicate what has been matched within these: `\( \)`

Comment: This will also delete any pair of successive double-quotes with no digits inside.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this -

```
:%s/"\(\d\+\)"/\1/c
```

Comment: `/c` will ask for confirmation, and only once per line. You at least want to add the `g` flag also.